# R: Highlighting Shiny data table

Tags: css, r, shiny, dt

I'm relatively new to R and trying to work with the Shiny package. 
I have something very similar to this: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/basic-datatable.html so we could work with the code there.

What I want to add is that some cells/rows become highlighted (either colourful background or colourful font). If you look at the example, I would like to have rows/cells (either whole row or just the cell, doesn't matter) red if the car has 8 or more cyl, yellow if it has 6 or less, green if it has 4 or less.

Is there any way to do it with the Shiny package? I've tried around with ShinyBS, but it doesn't do anything.

I've also seen this: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/datatables-demo.html. Sorted columns get a new colour here. This is at least a bit along the lines what I want, so I thought that CSS might be the answer but haven't gotten anywhere with it.

Hope anybody can help!

Comment: In www folder you can define style.css for Hilighting :)

Comment: Can you make an example?

Answer (score 3):

Without creating a new column:

```
jscode <- "
value <= 4 ? 'green' : (value <= 6 ? 'yellow' : (value >= 8 ? 'red' : 'white'))
"

datatable(mtcars) %>% formatStyle(
  "cyl", target = "row", 
  backgroundColor = JS(jscode))
```

or using the function `styleInterval`:

```
datatable(mtcars) %>% formatStyle(
  "cyl", target = "row", 
  backgroundColor = styleInterval(c(4, 6, 7), c("green", "yellow", "white", "red")))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `flag` field to match with colors and use `styleEqual` of ``DT```

```
df <- mtcars

df$colr_flag <- ifelse(df$cyl <= 4, 1, 
                    ifelse(df$cyl <=6, 2,
                           ifelse(df$cyl >=8, 3, 0)))


library(DT)
options(DT.options = list(pageLength = 5))
# style V6 based on values of V6
datatable(df) %>% formatStyle(
  'colr_flag', target = 'row', 
  backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(1, 2,3), c('green', 'yellow','red'))
)
```

[image]